# Android Icon for "open" or "load"

Tags: android, icons

Is there a built-in Android icon for "open" or "load"?  I'm making menu items, and I see `ic_menu_save`, but there's no `ic_menu_open` nor `ic_menu_load`.  I guess I could just use `ic_menu_add`, but that's not quite right.  I;m looking for a little folder or something.  Surely others have needed an open icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you browse the icons in your SDK, you will see that `ic_menu_archive` looks like an open folder. However, bear in mind that it looks like an open folder for stock Android -- these icons can be changed by device manufacturers. Google recommends that you copy these icons from your SDK into your project, so that you can have a consistent set within your app.

Answer (score 1):

Following on the approach of CommonsWare, in the last icon bundle (20131120), the more similar is `ic_action_collection` (open folder). (`ic_menu_save` is no more included.)